# How to replace just the specified characters

Tags: ruby, regex

For example:

```
specified_character = "你好啊"
str_to_replace1 = "你好啊朋友"
str_to_replace2 = "你好啊"
```

I want a regex to just match the whole `specified_character`. It says only `str_to_replace2` will match. I currently have:

```
/(?<=[^\p{Han}])#{specified_character}(?=[^\p{Han}])/
```

Result:

```
str_to_replace1 = "你好啊朋友"
str_to_replace2 = "new text"
```

Comment: It depends what regular expression you are using, it would probably be a good idea to post that as well.

Comment: Could you show what the results you are expected are ?

Comment: 你想取代成什麼？可否描述一下你想要的結果？你意思是不是想只match "你好啊"，而不match　"你好啊朋友"？

Comment: look into the [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a anchor to start(^) and end($)

```
pattern = /^Apple$/
'Apple'.gsub(pattern, 'Orange') # => 'Orange'
'Apple Pie'.gsub(pattern, 'Orange') # => 'Apple Pie'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if the string is the same as the pattern, then you should not be using a regex at all. Just use string comparison `==`.

```
specified_character = "你好啊"
str_to_replace1 = "你好啊朋友"
str_to_replace2 = "你好啊"

str_to_replace1 == specified_character # => false
str_to_replace2 == specified_character # => true
```